# How to upload files from a web app into Flash Media Server correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, file-upload, flash-media-server

My company is building Flash video web app which features uploading. I am in charge of this project, and have some and questions before I start to plan the structure and code.

We have a Windows server machine, running 2008, where we are going to host this app. We develop primarily in ASP.NET MVC using C#.

We are going to put the Flash Media Server on the same server machine. What I don't get is how will we be able to upload files into the Flash Media Server application folder where they need to be in order to work? We plan to upload FLVs.

Anybody care to explain how this is done? Any tips? Not asking for any code, just the understanding of how to approach this, the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

After a user uploads a file you can send it to pretty much wherever you want.  After the user uploads the file change the path to wherever the media server wants them and your done.

Comment: is that possible to upload to the fms folder? it is outside my root. and lets say I got this site hosted by somebody else and only got the fms on my server, I dont really know how that is done

Comment: You can save to any path on the hard drive.

Comment: Ok I will try that now, thanks. Then there is the scenario where it always not that easy that I got the app and Media Server on the same computer. What if I got the media server on a different computers?